For what $A$ the linear map $f(B):=AB^T+BA^T$ surjective, defined as a linear map between suitable vector spaces defined below?
Let $V$ denote the space of $m\times m$ real square matrices. Let $W$ denote the space of $m\times m$ real symmetric square matrices. For an $m\times m$ square (not necessarily symmetric) matrix $A,$ consider the linear map $T_A:V\to W$ defined by:
$$T_A(B):=AB^T+BA^T.$$
So we can think of $T_A$ as a linear map from $m^2$-dimensional vector space to a $\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$ - dimensional vector space.
I wonder for what $A,$ is $T_A$ surjective? And how does the rank of $T_A$ depend on $A?$ (I understand 'how' may be a bit vague, will think to make it more precise). For $A:=0_{m \times m},T_A$ has zero rank, since $T_0(B)=0 \forall B.$ For  $A:=I_{m \times m}, T_A=T_I$ has full rank, i.e. $T_I$ is surjective, since any symmetric matrix $S$ can be written as $T_I(S/2).$
My guess is that if $A$ is singular, i.e. $rank(A)<m,$ then $T_A$ won't be of full rank. The reason behind this guess is that if we consider instead $S_A(B):=AB^T,$ then $rank(S_A(B))<m \forall B,$ so $S_A$ is not surjective. But here, we can't say that $T_A$ is not surjective even if $rank(A)<m.$ Also if $A$ is nonsingular, can we say that $T_A$ has full rank?

$T_A$ is surjective if and only if $A$ is nonsingular.
If $A$ is singular, then $x^TA=0$ for some nonzero vector $x$. In turn, $x^TT_A(B)x=0$. Hence $T_A(B)$ cannot possibly be equal to $S=xx^T$, because $x^TSx=\|x\|^4\ne0$.
If $A$ is nonsingular, for any symmetric matrix $S$, we have $T_A(B)=S$ when $B=\frac{1}{2}S(A^{-1})^T$.

Thank you for your answer. I'll read it with attention. Is $x$ a row or a column vector, please?

@LearningMath Column vector.

Many thanks, I accepted your answer :)
